# Should you smooth a data vector before or after training?

Tags: regression, machine-learning, neural-networks

Suppose I want to use a deep neural network to map an input vector $x$ of length $a$, to an output vector $y$ of length $b$. In my training data, each $x$ is associated with a $y$. $y$ is a discretisation of a smooth function. However, I know that my measurements of $y$ in the training data are noisy.

So what I want to do is to do some smoothing on $y$. Which of the following two options is most sensible:

1) For each training datum, smooth the $y$, and then use this smoothed $y$ in the training pair.

2) Train with the original noisy $y$'s, and then smooth the output of the neural network.

Answer (score 2):

I'd be reluctant to do any smoothing of $y$ prior to modeling because then your model is no longer predicting $y$, but rather it's predicting what another of your models thinks $y$ should be.  But why should we believe the smoothed prediction more than the actual data?  This kind of uncertainty will be difficult to account for.

Furthermore, the fact that $y$ is noisy is not really something that's peculiar to your data set, it's characteristic of virtually *all* data sets.  We can think of most model fitting procedures as estimating parameters (most commonly expected values) of distributions, but we never actually observe these parameters in our data.  We observe the parameter plus or minus some noise, which is exactly the situation you describe.  The way to approach this is not to fit one model to $y$ and then another to $\hat{y}$, but instead to fit a single model that's capable of separating out the kind of noise to which you're referring.